# I18n in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, angular-translate

I18n key:

`"step1.download":"{{n0}} Download {{n1}} Some text."`

In my html:

```
<span translate=step1.download translate-values="{ n0: '{{info0}}', n1: '{{info1}}'}"></span>
```

In my controller:

```
$scope.download = function(){
        alert("fun executed");
        };
$scope.info0="<button ng-click=download()>";
$scope.info1="</button>";
```

I am getting an error that download function is not defined, I think because html parsed before angular compilation, so is there any way I can solve this problem. Alternatives solutions are also appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In html use "translate-compile" like this:

```
<span translate="step1.download" translate-compile translate-values="{ n0: '{{info0}}', n1: '{{info1}}'}"></span>
```

Worked with my case, it may depends on what translator you are using.It will work if you use "angular-translate.js".

Answer (score 1):

two things :

- You put a directive in the translate directive. There is no way your code works because the ng-click will be put in the DOM after angular parse it.
- It's not a good idea to put HTML as value in the translate directive. The module is make to handle text values and not HTML syntax.

For your problem, you have to make something like this :

```
{
    "step1.download":"Download",
    "step1.someText":"some text."
}
```

in your html :

```
<span>
    <button ng-click="download()">
        {{'step1.download'|translate}}
    </button> 
    {{'step1.someText'|translate}}
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for response, but i can not split those strings, so can you tell me how can i achieve this by adding a directive.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't split the text in two parts. For me, you can't do what you want without splitting the string.

Comment: The second string is not a full sentence so it is not going to translate separately, we are using our own translator and that part of code is much more complex, i have simplified for asking, by the way i got the solution i am going to post, thanks again.